# D3.js graph displaying only one dataset

Tags: d3.js

I having trouble getting the data on the graph. I only get one data set bar in.

You can see it here : http://infinite-fjord-1599.herokuapp.com/page2.html

But when I console.log the foreach for it. It displays all the objects:

```
  data.days.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d.values[name]}; });
    console.log(d.ages);
  });
```

[image]

The code on jsFiddle. [http://jsfiddle.net/arnir/DPM7y/](http://jsfiddle.net/NbuFJ/)

I'm very new to d3.js and working with json data so I'm kinda lost here. I took the example of the d3.js example site and modified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/NbuFJ/4/

You had a couple of issues here:

- Your `x0` scale was set to a domain that displayed a formatted date, but when you were calling it later you were passing in `d.State` (which didn't exist, so I assume it was a copy/paste error). So the later days were being rendered on top of the first day.
- There was a mismatch between the way you were selecting the group `g` element and the way you were appending it - not actually a root cause here, but likely to cause problems later on.

To fix, move the date formatting to a different function:

```
function formatDate(d) {
    var str = d.modified;
    d.date = parseDate( str.substring(0, str.length - 3) );
    var curr_month = d.date.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_date = d.date.getDate();
    var nicedate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month;
    return nicedate;
}
```

and then use the same function for the scale setup:

```
x0.domain(data.days.map(formatDate));
```

and the transform (note the fix in the selector and class here as well):

```
      var state = svg.selectAll("g.day")
          .data(data.days)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "day")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + x0(formatDate(d)) + ",0)";
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of small things that threw you off. First, the domain of the x0 scale should be an array of datetime objects, not an array of strings:

```
x0.domain(data.days.map(function(d) {
  var str = d.modified;
  d.date = parseDate( str.substring(0, str.length - 3) );
  return d.date;
}));
```

will return datetimes, not strings like it was before (minor nitpick: really not a fan of this use of `map`, I would add the date property separately in a forEach function as the data is loaded).

Second, x0 needs to be passed a property that actually exists:

```
var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
    .data(data.days)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.date) + ",0)"; });
```

Before, you were using `x0(d.state)` which is a vestige from the grouped bar example (several others still exist; I've changed the minimum to get your project working). Since the value didn't exist, all of the rectangles were getting drawn over each other.

Additionally, we need to format the axis labels so we aren't printing out the entire datetime object all over the labels:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m-%d"));
```

Finally, I noticed that the newest dates were being printed on the left instead of the right. You could sort the results of `data.days.map( ... )` to fix that, I just reversed the range of x0:

```
var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([width, 0], .1);
```

[fixed files](https://github.com/1wheel/learning/tree/master/stacktest/D3.js%20graph%20displaying%20only%20one%20dataset)

Comment: I think you'd need a `d3.time.scale` for real date objects, not just an ordinal scale...

Comment: x0 is an ordinal scale whose domain is an array of real data objects. I'm not sure if that is better than using a string to connect the scale to the data like you do though.

Comment: @AdamPearce - My mistake - I'm pretty sure older versions of D3 didn't deal correctly with Date objects in ordinal scales. FWIW, using a D3 ordinal scale for dates also converts the date to a string for use as a `d3.map` key - so there's no difference between my version and yours where that's concerned, as long as the strings are unique.